# How to use attrs to deserialize into immutable object from string?

Tags: python, python-attrs

I have a string log I'd like to deserialize into an object with as little boilerplate code as possible.

Current solution doesn't use attrs:

```
# @attr.s(frozen=True)
class MyLog():

    def __init__(self, log_str="a=1 b=2 c=3"):
        pairs = [pair.split('=') for pair in log_str.split(' ')]
        for k, v in pairs:
            print("{} = {}".format(k, v))
            # k = attr.ib(v)
        self.a = pairs[0][1]
        self.b = pairs[1][1]
        self.c = pairs[2][1]


print(MyLog().__dict__)
```

Can I use `attrs` to deserialize this log into an immutable object?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to let init take attribute values and use a factory method for the sort of conversion from string you propose above.

Below code isn't tested, but it demonstrates the idea:

```
@attr.s(frozen=True)
class MyLog():

    @classmethod
    def from_log_str(cls, log_str="a=1 b=2 c=3"):
        pairs = [pair.split("=") for pair in log_str.split(" ")]

        return cls(
            a=pairs[0][1],
            b=pairs[1][1],
            c=pairs[2][1],
        )

    a = attr.ib()
    b = attr.ib()
    c = attr.ib()

print(MyLog.from_log_str().__dict__)
```